# static HTML + Flask + Gunicorn works locally; breaks when pushed to heroku

Tags: python, git, heroku, flask, gunicorn

I just made a little flask app, and it works locally, but when I try to push it to heroku something breaks when serving the static HTML (self-diagnosed, when I make flask return just text and not a static html file everything works as expected.)

I tried following this guide..
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python
here is an LS from my directory

```
Procfile        account.pyc     base.pyc        requirements.txt    venv
account.py      base.py         home.html       templates
```

here is the code from some pertinent files.

requirements.txt

```
Flask==0.10.1
Jinja2==2.7.1
MarkupSafe==0.18
Werkzeug==0.9.4
gunicorn==18.0
heroku==0.1.4
httplib2==0.8
itsdangerous==0.23
oauth2==1.5.211
python-dateutil==1.5
requests==2.0.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

gitignore

```
venv
*.pyc
```

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn base:app
```

account.py (The thing that fetches data from my stockbroker )

```
 token    = oauth.Token(key=_ACCESS_TOKEN_, secret=_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET_)
 consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=_CONSUMER_KEY_, secret=_CONSUMER_SECRET_)
 request_holdings_url = "%s/accounts/%s/holdings.json" % (_BASE_URL_, _ACCOUNT_NUMBER_)
 request_values_url = "%s/market/ext/quotes.xml?" % _BASE_URL_
 #creating the client
 client = oauth.Client(consumer, token=token)

 #making the request via the client

 stocksym = {}


 def urlquery():
 # get all of my tradeking info
     resp, content = client.request(request_holdings_url, "GET")
     content =  json.loads(content)
     return content


 def getstocksym(json):
     # returns the holdings under my TK acct
     allholdings = json[u"response"][u"accountholdings"][u"holding"]
     for stock in allholdings:
         sym = stock[u"instrument"][u"sym"]
         stocksym.update({sym: 0})
     return stocksym


 def stockvalue(stocks):
     # returns a dictionary with stock: price: change:
     stockvalues = {}
     for stock in stocks:
         resp, content = client.request("https://api.tradeking.com/v1/market/ext/quotes.json?symbols=%s" % stock, "GET")
         content = json.loads(content)
         change = content[u"response"][u"quotes"][u"quote"][u"chg_sign"]
         price = content[u"response"][u"quotes"][u"quote"][u"ask"]
         stockvalues.update({stock: {'price':price, 'change':change}})
     return stockvalues

 def parsevalues(stockvalues):
     #parses library, returns whether or not a stock in the dictionary is changing, and what price it is.
     values = []
     for stock in stockvalues:
         price = stockvalues[stock][u"price"]
         if stockvalues[stock][u"change"] == 'u':
             return "%s is going up! and the price is: %s" % (stock, price)
         elif stockvalues[stock][u"change"] == 'd':
            return "%s is going down! and the price is %s" % (stock, price)


 if __name__ == "__main__":
    parsevalues(stockvalue(getstocksym(urlquery())))
```

base.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template
import account
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def home():
   values = account.stockvalue(account.getstocksym(account.urlquery()))
   json = jsonify(values)
   json = values
   return render_template('home.html', json=json)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run()
```

home.html

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
     <head>
         <title> 
            stock app! 
         </title>
     </head>
     <body>
         <ul>
             {% for stock, attr in json.iteritems() %}
                 <li>

                 {{ stock }} - {{attr.price}} <div style="display: inline-block; width: 10px; height: 10px; border-radius: 5px; background-color: {% if attr.    change == 'u' %} green  {% else %} red {% endif %}"></div>

                 </li>

             {% endfor %}
         </ul>
     </body>
 </html>
```

The app now runs successfully locally with a foreman start.

```
(venv)Eriks-MacBook-Pro:stockheroku erikmingo$ foreman start
17:57:31 web.1  | started with pid 752
17:57:32 web.1  | 2013-10-21 17:57:32 [752] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
17:57:32 web.1  | 2013-10-21 17:57:32 [752] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (752)
17:57:32 web.1  | 2013-10-21 17:57:32 [752] [INFO] Using worker: sync
17:57:32 web.1  | 2013-10-21 17:57:32 [755] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 755
```

So at this point I run:

```
git add .
git commit -m "this works locally, maybe it will work on heroku!"
git push heroku master
```

gives me back this :

```
Counting objects: 9, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 463 bytes, done.
Total 5 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Python app detected
-----> No runtime.txt provided; assuming python-2.7.4.
-----> Using Python runtime (python-2.7.4)
-----> Installing dependencies using Pip (1.3.1)
       Cleaning up...
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web

-----> Compiled slug size: 29.5MB
-----> Launching... done, v28
       http://still-fortress-2740.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:still-fortress-2740.git
   34025ca..ecba67c  master -> master
```

When I enter heroku open I get a 500 error.

Here are the heroku logs:

```
2013-10-22T01:26:32.722581+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=still-fortress-2740.herokuapp.com fwd="67.176.81.118" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30ms status=500 bytes=135
2013-10-22T01:26:32.723565+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
2013-10-22T01:26:32.723565+00:00 app[web.1]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2013-10-22T01:26:32.723806+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
2013-10-22T01:26:32.723806+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2013-10-22T01:26:32.723806+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
2013-10-22T01:26:32.723806+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2013-10-22T01:26:32.723806+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
2013-10-22T01:26:32.723806+00:00 app[web.1]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2013-10-22T01:26:32.723806+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
2013-10-22T01:26:32.723806+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2013-10-22T01:26:32.723806+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
2013-10-22T01:26:32.723806+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2013-10-22T01:26:32.723983+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/base.py", line 8, in home
2013-10-22T01:26:32.723983+00:00 app[web.1]:     values = account.stockvalue(account.getstocksym(account.urlquery()))
2013-10-22T01:26:32.723983+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/account.py", line 28, in urlquery
2013-10-22T01:26:32.723983+00:00 app[web.1]:     resp, content = client.request(request_holdings_url, "GET")
2013-10-22T01:26:32.723983+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2/__init__.py", line 682, in request
2013-10-22T01:26:32.723983+00:00 app[web.1]:     connection_type=connection_type)
2013-10-22T01:26:32.723983+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1570, in request
2013-10-22T01:26:32.723983+00:00 app[web.1]:     (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
2013-10-22T01:26:32.723983+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1317, in _request
2013-10-22T01:26:32.723983+00:00 app[web.1]:     (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
2013-10-22T01:26:32.724435+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1252, in _conn_request
2013-10-22T01:26:32.724435+00:00 app[web.1]:     conn.connect()
2013-10-22T01:26:32.724435+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1044, in connect
2013-10-22T01:26:32.724435+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise SSLHandshakeError(e)
2013-10-22T01:26:32.724435+00:00 app[web.1]: SSLHandshakeError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

This is my first post ever on stackoverlow, I tried my best to follow the posting guidelines. Let me know if you any other information would be helpful... Like I mentioned above, when I change the return of the "/" route, to just a string, the app works on heroku.

Thanks in advance!

edit: It appears the issue is with my API call... Heroku is saying it's a bad SSL handshake or something... What does this really mean, though? It is definitely something in my account.py file, but I am not sure what.

Comment: About bad SSL handshake see latest edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has to be some kind of problem with `account` module. When I create dummy `account` like this:

```py
def stockvalue(foo):
    return {'foo': 'bar'}

def getstocksym(foo):
    return None

def urlquery():
    return None
```

everything works smoothly.

**Edit**

Try replacing `home` with this and see what you get:

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
   try:
       values = account.stockvalue(account.getstocksym(account.urlquery()))
   except Exception as e:
       return jsonify({"error": str(e)})
   return jsonify(values)
```

Or even better add `app.config['DEBUG'] = True` after `app = Flask(__name__)`. Don't forget to remove it in production. While it is useful for debugging it not really safe

**Another edit**

It looks like you have problem with missing certificates. It **should** help:

1. Download certificates from curl site: http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
2. Copy `cacert.pem` to the root dir of your app (where `account.py` is located)
3. `git add .`
4. Modify `account.py`

```py
import os
import oauth2 as oauth
# Other imports

token    = oauth.Token(key=_ACCESS_TOKEN_, secret=_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET_)
consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=_CONSUMER_KEY_, secret=_CONSUMER_SECRET_)
request_holdings_url = "%s/accounts/%s/holdings.json" % (_BASE_URL_, _ACCOUNT_NUMBER_)
request_values_url = "%s/market/ext/quotes.xml?" % _BASE_URL_

#creating the client
client = oauth.Client(consumer, token=token)
client.ca_certs = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'cacert.pem')

#Rest of your code
...
```

Commit and push to Heroku.

Comment: Hmm well. When I try to make the render_template return a hello world-esque html doc that doesn't work either. Let me upload some of the code from account.py (I don't want to show my tokens etc).

Comment: There is a lot going on inside accounts. Try running your app with code from edit and see what you get. It should narrow the search.

Comment: works locally and gives me

"{
  "GGG": {
    "change": "u", 
    "price": "80.8400"
  }, 
  "ONVO": {
    "change": "u", 
    "price": "6.2500"
  }
}
"

breaks remotely... Will try using your code instead. Do you think heroku is maybe having trouble making the HTTP requests to tradeking?

Comment: works locally, breaks on heroku.... I can't even get the html file
<html>
<body>
<h1> hi world! </h1>
</body>
</html>
to work though...

Comment: you were right, it's something with the account module! Whoopie!

check it out it works with the mock dicttionary
http://still-fortress-2740.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Woa I think I found what's going on... not necessarily sure how to fix it. going to post some logs in the body of this post... I have to do some reading on try-except, and dict.get... very very very new to this.

Comment: wow dude awesome. I will read up on what that cert actually is but that did the trick thanks a bunch!